# Alignment of stack variables in Assembly Languages

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86, masm, memory-alignment

Are there any assembly directives to align specific **stack data** variables?

For example, suppose a MASM function has these local variables with initial values

```
LOCAL           beginStack:QWORD         ; ffffffffdeadbeef
LOCAL           myLocalA:QWORD           ; ffffffffffffffff
LOCAL           myLocalB:QWORD           ; 0000000000000000
LOCAL           myArrayA[10]:BYTE        ; AAAAAAAAAA
LOCAL           myArrayB[10]:BYTE        ; BBBBBBBBBB
LOCAL           endStack:QWORD           ; ffffffffbaadf00d
```

The memory stack has this layout but notice `endStack` is misaligned

```
00000048`51effb60 baadf00d000906ec  ; baadf00d
00000048`51effb68 42424242ffffffff  ; ffffffff
00000048`51effb70 4141424242424242 
00000048`51effb78 4141414141414141 
00000048`51effb80 0000000000000000 
00000048`51effb88 ffffffffffffffff 
00000048`51effb90 ffffffffdeadbeef
```

To align `endStack`, I've tried to intermingle the local variables with an alignment `pad[4]`

```
LOCAL           beginStack:QWORD
LOCAL           myLocalA:QWORD
LOCAL           myLocalB:QWORD
LOCAL           myArrayA[10]:BYTE
LOCAL           myArrayB[10]:BYTE
LOCAL           pad[4]:BYTE
LOCAL           endStack:QWORD
```

which does correctly align `endStack`

```
0000005b`950ff950 ffffffffbaadf00d  ; aligned
0000005b`950ff958 42424242ffdaf38f  ; pad[4] is ffdaf38f
0000005b`950ff960 4141424242424242 
0000005b`950ff968 4141414141414141 
0000005b`950ff970 0000000000000000 
0000005b`950ff978 ffffffffffffffff 
0000005b`950ff980 ffffffffdeadbeef
```

Another approach (if applicable) is to reshuffle the stack variables based upon a descending hierarchy
`QWORD` -> `DWORD` -> `WORD` -> `BYTE`

**Question**

GCC has this `__attribute__ ((aligned (8)))` to align variables but is there an equivalent method for assembly languages?

It does feel like the higher level languages such as C/C++ have a large toolbox of nice optimization tricks, but unfortunately are not ported over to lower level assembly languages.

Comment: MASM is actually kind of unusual in having the LOCAL directive to compute these things for you at all.  With most assemblers, you would simply be expected to compute the stack frame offsets by hand and hardcode them.  Usually, the point of writing in assembly is that you want to do all optimization yourself; the assembler's job is to encode exactly what you wrote and to otherwise get out of the way.

Comment: I guess one way is to just put all the locals in a `struc`. A `struc` can take an alignment value (ie: 8 or QWORD) and it will align the elements accordingly. It is a bit of extra work but it would do the trick. An example is here:  https://pastebin.com/4cLWm0f1

Comment: @Michael Petch Thanks for this very nice original idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The partial answer so far is to define a MASM macro `aligned` which inserts padding bytes to both DWORD and WORD variables to keep them 8 byte aligned in 64-bit.

This crude macro accepts a DWORD or WORD variable then determines the number of padding bytes. To prevent duplicate symbol errors, it defines a local `num` which generates unique labels each time the macro is invoked. The output is the local variable itself followed by the padding: `LOCAL pad??0001[4]` for a DWORD or `LOCAL pad??0001[6]` for a WORD.

```
aligned MACRO var
LOCAL num
IF @InStr(1,<var>,<:DWORD>) NE 0
  padBytes = 4
ELSEIF @InStr(1,<var>,<:WORD>) NE 0
  padBytes = 6
ENDIF
var
@CatStr(<LOCAL pad>,<num>,<[padBytes]:BYTE>)
ENDM
```

To keep this similar to other C/C++ alignments, the LOCAL's are prefixed with an `aligned` macro call

```
main proc   
    aligned LOCAL AppleA:WORD
    aligned LOCAL AppleB:DWORD    
    aligned LOCAL AppleC:WORD
    aligned LOCAL AppleD:DWORD      
    
    LOCAL OrangeA:WORD
    LOCAL OrangeB:DWORD    
    LOCAL OrangeC:WORD
    LOCAL OrangeD:DWORD         
       
    mov AppleA,1
    mov AppleB,2
    mov AppleC,3
    mov AppleD,4   
    
    mov OrangeA,5
    mov OrangeB,6
    mov OrangeC,7
    mov OrangeD,8      
   
    ret
main endp

end
```

The memory stack from running the code shows

```
00000030`f1b1fb10 00077ff600000008   ; OrangeD 8 is misaligned
00000030`f1b1fb18 00057ff600000006   ; OrangeB 6 is misaligned
00000030`f1b1fb20 000000040000001f   ; AppleD 4 is aligned
00000030`f1b1fb28 0003000000000000   ; AppleC 3 is aligned
00000030`f1b1fb30 0000000200000000   ; AppleB 2 is aligned
00000030`f1b1fb38 00017ff6915ae298   ; AppleA 1 is aligned
```

**Notes**

As noted in the comments, this macro does not parse arrays yet. A solution is to use the MASM MOD operator which returns the integer value of the remainder (modulo) when dividing *expression1* by *expression2*. The idea would be to accept an array, say `aligned LOCAL myArrayA[10]:BYTE`, extract the `arraySize` of 10 then calculate the required padding bytes 6 using

```
padBytes = (8 - (arraySize MOD 8))
```

**Edited**

Michael Petch suggested a very clever and unique approach by putting all the locals in a struc. A struc can take an alignment value (ie: 8 or QWORD) and it will align the elements accordingly. It is a bit of extra work but it would do the trick. An example is here: pastebin.com/4cLWm0f1

```
.code
main PROC
    main_locs STRUC QWORD           ; 8 byte (QWORD) alignment
        beginStack DQ ?
        myLocalA   DQ ?
        myLocalB   DQ ?
        myArrayA   BYTE 10 DUP (?)
        myArrayB   BYTE 10 DUP (?)
        endStack   DQ ?
    main_locs ENDS
    LOCAL stack_vars: main_locs
 
    lea rcx, stack_vars
    mov [rcx][main_locs.beginStack], 0ffffffffdeadbeefh
    mov [rcx][main_locs.myLocalA],   0ffffffffffffffffh
    mov [rcx][main_locs.myLocalB],   00000000000000000h
    ;Fill myArrayA with 10 As
    mov rax, "AAAAAAAA"
    mov QWORD PTR[rcx][main_locs.myArrayA], rax
    mov WORD  PTR[rcx][main_locs.myArrayA+8], ax
    ;Fill myArrayB with 10 Bs
    mov rax, "BBBBBBBB"
    mov QWORD PTR[rcx][main_locs.myArrayB], rax
    mov WORD  PTR[rcx][main_locs.myArrayB+8], ax
    mov [rcx][main_locs.endStack], 0ffffffffbaadf00dh
    ret
main ENDP
 
end
```

Comment: Does this work for `aligned LOCAL    myArrayA[10]:BYTE`?  Or only for separate scalar word or dword variables, where it's usually not useful to have it at the start of an aligned qword?  Aligning the start of an array can make sense, e.g. for use with SSE2, but it's kind of silly *not* to put a separate dword and/or a word in the 6 bytes left over in the 16 bytes containing an aligned 10-byte array.  (Unless you want to be able to store garbage there as part of a `movaps` store.)

Comment: Also, this seems to declare the padding *after* the local variable, so you have to declare all your "aligned" variables first, and rely on MASM laying them out in source order.  I'm sure that works in practice, but I wonder if it's guaranteed on paper anywhere.  Not that it matters much in practice, unless MASM ever changes or compatible assemblers like JWASM are different.

Comment: Honestly I don't see much value in this, especially if it doesn't work for arrays; if you want a tool to do this for you, write in C and use `alignas(8) int32_t foo;`; the compiler can still pack locals optimally while respecting alignment constraints.  If you're hand-writing in asm, lay out your locals yourself if the layout matters.  My impression is that MASM's "high level" stuff was maybe appropriate a few decades ago when whole projects were written in asm, and some people were stuck writing asm even if they didn't really want to be.  It's often best avoided these days.